# suggest an alternative query for this type of condition in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

suggest an alternative query for this type of condition in sql

```
select v_sdi_previous_id,v_sdi_settlement_flag,v_sdi_studentid 
    from schooldev."STUDENT_DETAILS_INFO" 
    where (upper(v_sdi_studentid)=upper('BS15B016') or (upper(v_sdi_previous_id)=('BS15B016')) )
    and n_sdi_schoolid='1' and v_sdi_active_flag='Y'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty simple query. What alternative you want ?
You may use IN instead of multiple OR like-

```
where upper(v_sdi_studentid) IN ('BS15B016', 'BS15B016')
and n_sdi_schoolid='1' and v_sdi_active_flag='Y'.
```

Nothing much is needed with this query unless you are not getting the output as per your need.

Comment: Sure. Please upvote the answer. Please accept it as correct answer to your question.

Comment: Not update. I am asking to upvote my answer and accept it as correct answer. Please check again.

Comment: You can click on upward arrow. Right now you are seeing 0 here Upward arrow just above it. And to accept answer, click on the check mark beside the answer and it will become green.

Answer (score 0):

select v_sdi_studentid as new_id,v_sdi_previous_id,v_sdi_settlement_flag from schooldev."STUDENT_DETAILS_INFO" where upper(v_sdi_previous_id) IN ('BS15B016') and n_sdi_schoolid='1' and v_sdi_active_flag='Y'